# page-break-after css property not working when I am printing my web page with some dynamic content

Tags: html, css, printing

I want a page break after some dynamic content on a web page while printing but `page-break-after` is not working. Here is my code. I want a page break after class, `dc` as it is a sub `div` inside a container so I used a page break inside the `.container` class. Note: ROW COLUMN and container are Bootstrap 4 classes.

```css
@media print {
  html,
  body {
    width: 210mm;
    height: auto;
  }
  .jumbotron {
    display: none;
  }
  .container {
    width: 210mm;
    page-break-after: always;
  }
  .img {
    height: 297mm;
    width: 210mm;
  }
  .img2 {
    height: 297mm;
    width: 210mm;
    position: relative;
  }
  .contentoverimage {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 290px;
    height: 200px;
    color: white;
  }
  .contentoverimage .p1 {
    font-family: 'Century Gothic';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    \ font-size: 64px;
    line-height: 78px;
    text-decoration-line: underline;
  }
  .frontpage {
    font-family: 'Century Gothic';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .contentovertitle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 20%;
    right: 20%;
    color: white;
  }
  .backtitleheading {
    font-family: 'Century Gothic';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 25px;
  }
  .backtitlecontent {
    text-align: justify;
    font-family: 'Century Gothic';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .titlenames {
    font-family: 'Century Gothic';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .dc {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 20%;
    right: 20%;
  }
  .dcheading {
    font-family: 'Century Gothic';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 25px;
  }
  .dccontent {
    text-align: justify;
    font-family: 'Century Gothic';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container text-center">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <img src="images/titlelife.png" class="img2" />
      <div class="dc">
        <p class="dcheading">
          <?php echo $row['fname2']; ?>, Your Life Path is</p>
        <br><br>
        <p class="dccontent"> DYNAMIC CONTENT MAY BE ONE TWO THREE FOUR A$ SIZE PAGES</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```